# Resforce SOQL Query Error Bind variables only allowed in Apex code

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, salesforce, soql, databasedotcom-gem

I have a controller action that needs to take the Account ID of the logged in user (parent) and make a SOQL query to find all of children associated with the parent. I receive the following error:

```
Bind variables only allowed in Apex code
```

After searching around I've learned that I can't use a variable in my SOQL query. However, I am looking for some help as to pull multiple children on a parent using a dynamic parent ID. My query currently looks like this:

```
@loanparts = client.query("select Loan_Risk__c from Loan_Part__c where Account__c = @account.Account__c")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to pass accountid as string, I don't know which programming language are you using. 
Please try this.

@loanparts = client.query("select Loan_Risk__c from Loan_Part__c where Account__c ='+AccountId+'")

Comment: I'm using ruby. This worked perfectly. I just needed to convert accountid as a string. Thank you!